# Agregar Tablas existentes al Panel Admin en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

resulta que estoy migrando a Django, tengo mi base de datos en Mysql.
El problema es que cuando realizo un nueva tabla desde mi modelo en django, todo indica y se me muestra en el panel admin sin problemas.

El problema está cuando intento agregar esta tabla en mi panel Admin de django. Realizo las migraciones y me resultan correctas.

Muestro mi código de la tabla que si se muestra:

```
class CategoryEmployee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nombre')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Categoria Empleado'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categorias Empleados'
        db_table = 'empleadocategoria'
        ordering = ['id']
```

Y este es mi codigo de la tabla que no se muestra:

```
class Categorias(models.Model):
    cat_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=45, db_collation='latin1_swedish_ci')
    statusinterno = models.IntegerField(db_column='statusInterno')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechaalta = models.DateTimeField(db_column='fechaAlta')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechaedit = models.DateTimeField(db_column='fechaEdit', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    parent_pk = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Categoria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categorias'
        ordering = ['cat_id']
        db_table = 'categorias'
```

Espero puedan apoyarme a solucionar este inconveniente, ya he consultado pero no he tenido exito.
Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta registrar tu módelo en el admin.

> admin.py

```
class CategoriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nombre', )

admin.site.register(Categorias, CategoriasAdmin)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: te mega amo pana rabit. Solucionado :D